# How to convert base64 encoded string to HTTP::FormData::File in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, base64

I have a base64 encoded string of a pdf file, which I can decode using Ruby

```
Base64.decode(the_string)
```

Now I want to convert it to an object of type `HTTP::FormData::File` which I can then upload using http post to AWS S3.

How do I do this ***WITHOUT*** writing out the file to disk and reading it back in using

```
HTTP::FormData::File.new("/path/to/file.pdf")
```

Thank you

Comment: What is `HTTP::FormData::File`? It's not part of the standard library. Is it supplied by some gem? If so, you need to edit your question to include that information, and a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using the [http-form_data gem](https://github.com/httprb/form_data.rb). In that case, your answer is in the very first example in the [HTTP::FormData::File docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/http-form_data/HTTP/FormData/File). For posterity:

> #### Usage with StringIO
>
> ```
> io = StringIO.new "foo bar baz"
> FormData::File.new io, :filename => "foobar.txt"
> ```

And so:

```
require "stringio"
require "base64"

io = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(the_string))
file = HTTP::FormData::File.new(io, filename: "some_filename.txt")
```